# Eliminar plugin de elementos Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin, jquery-plugins

Estoy utilizando el plugin lightcase.js para hacer un carousel de imagenes. ¿Como puedo eliminar el plugin de los elementos en los cuales he inicializado el plugin, mediante la instrucción:

```
$("a.item-lightcase").lightcase({
    transition: 'scrollHorizontal'
});
```

Lo que quiero es eliminar el plugin de los elementos cuando quiera, e inicializarlo cuando quiera.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? ¿Donde te aparece el error? ¿Puedes colocar el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: $('a.item-gallery').lightcase({
   transition: 'scrollHorizontal',
                showSequenceInfo: false,
                showTitle: false
            });

Tras esto lo que me gustaría es quitar el plugin sobre los elementos a los que se los acabo de poner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo plugin suele tener un .destroy() o .close(), prueba:

```
$("a.item-lightcase").destroy();
$("a.item-lightcase").close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea una instancia de la clase:

```
var gallery = $("#a.item-lightcase").lightcase({
    transition: 'scrollHorizontal'
});
```

Luego eliminale la instancia con `destroy()`, de la siguiente manera:

```
gallery.destroy();
```